TV show with paranoid people in therapy
So I can only remember seeing one episode. I want to say it was either from the late 90s to early 2000s. The basis of the show was there was groups of people in therapy for severe paranoia.
I remember at one point this guy was convinced his neighbor was listening through his walls so he was stapling egg cartons onto the wall to prevent the guy from hearing in.
Another scene was the guy was in a bar attempting to hit on a girl and she asked him if he liked people. He responded with "I find them terrifying" and she looks at him strange and says, "I meant the magazine." And he awkwardly says, "me too."  I know it's not a lot to go on but I figured there has to be someone else out there he might remember a show like this.
It was American. I watched in on TV at my mom's house one day. It's the only time I remember seeing it. My mom doesn't remember it though. I can't even tell you what channel it was on. Just that it was a comedy tv show about some paranoid people in therapy.

Hi. Was it American? Where did you see it?

Yes it was American. I watched in on TV at my mom's house one day. It's the only time I remember seeing it. My mom doesn't remember it though. I can't even tell you what channel it was on. Just that it was a comedy tv show about some paranoid people in therapy.

Sounds like the ABC comedy The Trouble with Normal that ran for a single short season in 2000.

The misadventures of four paranoid young men whose fear of urban conspiracy leads them to seek counseling in a therapy group run by therapist Claire Garletti.

One of them (David Krumholtz) glues egg cartons to the walls and windows of his house to soundproof it in the pilot. Also starred Paget Brewster and Jon Cryer. Here's a clip from that pilot:




Yes that's it!!! Thank you so much!

@AshleyN. No problem! But don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.
